# How to disable certain bibtex properties from appearing in bbl?

Tags: bibtex

as the title suggests, I have BibTeX entries with e.g. page numbers and URLs.

I want to keep this information in my BIB (which is managed by JabRef) but I want to choose which properties appear in the final PDF.

For example I do not want the pages to appear. How do I do this without removing it from the BIB (it wouldn't be restorable)

Comment: I think *biblatex* is everywhere superior package to the vanilla *bibtex*. If you use *biblatex*, You can use `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{pages}}` to disable page numbers. For other fields such as month, replaces *pages* with *month*. For a list of fields, refer to BibTeX manual section 2.2.2.

Comment: you need to find an appropriate `bst` file, or modify/create one.  look for `custom-bib`.

Comment: @MobiusPizza Want to write up an answer to that question to get it off the list of unanswered?

Comment: @Johannes_B sure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest method is to use the `biblatex` package instead of classical BibTeX to handle bibliographies and references. `Biblatex` uses the same `.bib` files as BibTeX.

You can use general purpose hooks such as `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{pages}}` (see [BibLaTex documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) section 4.10.6) to suppress page numbers within a specific LaTeX document without the need to modify the contents of the .bib file. For any other fields such as month, simply replace the field name “pages” with “month” as in `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}`. Similarly, for a list of fields, refer to [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) section 2.2.2.